# Command conditional on parameters: Set optional parameter

Tags: macros

I'm typesetting some group theory notes and wanted to construct a command `\iso` with the following use cases:

1. `\iso` will generate `\varphi`;
2. `\iso{a}` will generate `\varphi\left(a\right)`.

Is such a construction possible? Something similar that is still efficient would also be appropriate as long as it can satisfy similar use cases. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. It's somewhat possible, but the syntax is horrible. And you don't really need `\left` and `\right`, generally speaking.

Comment: `\left\right` would make bad space here, don't you want `\varphi(a)` ? also while it's possible (the deprecated `xparse`  `g` argument type)  standard latex syntax uses `[]` for optional arguments ,so `\iso[a]`although `\iso(a)` reads better and requires no code.

Comment: You're right that `\left` and `\right` are bad here. I'm a computer scientist so I'm pretty specific about how I set up commands and functions like this - just a style choice. I'll look into the workaround you suggested even though it's not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: What TeX format do you wish to use for doing this? LaTeX 2e? plain TeX?